# Can men and women stand next to each other during congregational prayers?

Tags: sharia, salat, jamaat

Is it permissible for men and women to stand next to each other and mixed together during congregational prayer? Will their prayers be void?

*Source required.*

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not permissible until there is a veil between them such that men cannot see women and women cannot see men.

It is permissible that men be in the front and women in back of them, but not side-by-side

---

References:

- [www.leader.ir](http://www.leader.ir/tree/index.php?catid=23)
- [makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/compilation/Reader.aspx?lid=1&pid=61941&catid=6520)

Comment: -1 for "it is not possible until be a veil between them such that men cannot see women and women cannot see men".

Comment: By "possible", he might have meant "permissible".

Answer (score 1):

No, men and women cannot stand next to each other.  It is not the women place to be up with the men, nor is it a mans place to be back with the women, they each have their position, men are in front and women are in the back.

> عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، قَالَ صَلَّيْتُ أَنَا وَيَتِيمٌ، فِي
>   بَيْتِنَا خَلْفَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَأُمِّي أُمُّ سُلَيْمٍ
>   خَلْفَنَا
>
> Narrated Anas bin Malik:
>
> One night an orphan and I offered the prayers behind the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   in my house and my mother (Um Sulaim) was standing behind us (by
>   herself forming a row).

[صحيح البخاري (Bukari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/121)

Also note, that this hadith is proof that a women should not stand with the men, even if it is her Maharim.